# Using the command prompt, how do I delete files of a certain size?

Tags: command, cmd, prompt

Using the command prompt, once in the appropriate directory, how do I delete files of a specific type and size?  I think the following code will apply, but want to make sure.

I want to delete all xml files that are equal to a file size of 0 -
del *.xml = 0

Answer (score 1):

Try this loop:

```
FOR %%F IN (*.xml) DO IF %%~zF EQU 0 DEL %%F
```

Reference: [DOS Script Snippets](http://www.dostips.com/DtCodeSnippets.php)

**Edit:**

Per your comment, try creating the following as a batch file and execute that:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR %%F IN (*.xml) DO IF %%~zF EQU 0 DEL %%F
```

Comment: When I run this in the directory I am searching for, I get the following - %%F was unexpected at this time.